# Android Can't Find Application icon

Tags: android, android-emulator

I create an Android Application on eclipse ,  when i want to run it  on the Emulator  I get The message saying

> MyApplicationName.apk installed on device

So normally every thing fine.

But when i want to start my application i did not find it's icon. 
And when i go to `parametres`  then `manage applications` i find it there.

Can anyone tell me why i am not able to find the application's icon on the Emulator ?

here is the manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.enis.testandroid"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="MainActivity" />
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: can you put up your manifest file most probably you removed category - launcher from manifest

Comment: As @SunnyKumarAditya suggests, the `<intent-filter>` for your 'main' `Activity` must have action `MAIN` and category `LAUNCHER`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have missed to add a Launcher in your Manifest file,

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/download" <!-- Check this one -->
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".abc"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" /> <!-- Check this one -->
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="abc" >
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="def" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<application
        android:name="com.x.y.z"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@android:string/abc" >
```

In manifest, make changes according to your drawable folder icon. Also make sure to use small case for drawable.